# Cannot transfer user files to new owner

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to transfer users files to owner but drive api still responses with `insufficientFilePermissions` or `invalidSharingRequest` error

- `insufficientFilePermissions` - when firstly add `writer` permission to admin user and then update permission to `owner` and transfer ownership
- `invalidSharingRequest` - first step is create new permission to admin user and transfer ownership

These errors are documented here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors and I think all is ok - sharing settings should be set, both users are active (not suspended), and superadmin account has writer permission

I'm using drive api methods [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) and [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) for example code looks like this

```js
const drive = google.drive({ auth, version: 'v3' });
const permission = await drive.permissions.create({
    fileId: file.id,
    transferOwnership: true,
    requestBody: {
            role: 'owner',
            emailAddress: ownerEmail, // new owner email
            type: 'user',
        },
    });
```

I'm quite sure the code is right.

**IMPORTANT NOTES**

- users are in same domain and files are in drive folder under this domain and superadmin is owner of this folder
- `auth` is `google.auth.JWT` with our service account info and impersonation email - its our gsuite superadmin account
- used scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

The problem is that owner can transfer files ownership to another users but as admin in script I cannot transfer these files.
I dont know what is wrong, do you have some ideas? We have basic google plan, should we switch to business plan for a right working? Or is there some advanced settings?

I am really tired and without any other ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information of method for creating the file you want to create the permissions?

Comment: Only users in drive are creating these files, we want to transfer ownership when some of these users ends the cooperation with our company, we dont want to do it manually

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the users create the files using the Service account, the permissions of files can be modified by the service account. So in your situation, I thought that when the users created a file, the owner might be required to be changed to the service account. Because I thought that the owner of the file is not the Service account, such error occurs. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: But how can I switch to new owner via script if I dont have permission to do it - problem is described above. Our employees wont switch owner of the file to service account user

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot know about the method for modifying the permissions of the files that the owner is other user. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.